# Prevent JQuery Mobile collapsible set header from being truncated

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery mobile's collapsible set, and my long header titles are being truncated (and made unreadable) when viewed on mobile devices.

For example the header defined here:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>My header with lots of text that gets truncated when viewing on mobile device or small screen.</h3>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    ...
```

Ends up being truncated to:
    My header with lots of text...

Following the advice of other posts, I tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ui-header .ui-title .ui-btn-text .ui-collapsible-heading {
    overflow: visible !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
  }
</style>
```

...to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the necessary CSS to make the title of a collapsible set multi-line:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content .ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-text {
    white-space : normal;
}​
```

Notice I targeted the `.ui-btn-text` element that is a descendant of the `.ui-collapsible-heading` element to get the desired effect.

This makes a very specific rule that will overwrite the default jQuery Mobile styling without the need to use `!important`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JaPdC/

Comment: Just FYI, this works great in Chrome, but does not appear to work for Safari webkit in iPhone.  Investigating why this is the case