# jqm Long collapsible headers trucated

Tags: jquery-mobile

We need to have a multiline label in collapsibles, since they get truncated en JQM 1.4 or more

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>My header with long text that truncated when viewing on mobile device or small     screens.</h3>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    ...

A solution that worked for jqm 1.3 was:

.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content .ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-text {
        white-space : normal;
}?
```

truncated/10254192#10254192

As indicated in:
[Prevent JQuery Mobile collapsible set header from being truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253917/prevent-jquery-mobile-collapsible-set-header-from-being-)

Nevetheless, since jqm version 1.4 deprecated .ui-btn-text, that solution does not work anymore

Question: How can I avoid long texts to be truncated? or in other words, how to get multi-line labels for collapsibles?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text is directly contained in the anchor tag with a class of ui-collapsible-heading-toggle. So this should work:

```
.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
    white-space : normal;
}
```